# Text different after changing application region for iOS app

Tags: ios

After changing the application region for my app to test currency formatting I noticed that the text of all labels/buttons have changed to capital letters. I first thought it might just be inherent to the region, but it has happened with multiple regions around Europe. I am using system font for all labels/buttons. If anyone has any idea, please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

Oops, found the answer.

There is an option to "Show non-localized strings."

Google Detecting Non-localized Strings for more information.